# IHP: can't load framework: Cocoa (not found)

Tags: ihp

I created a new IHP project and when I run it for the first time it gives me this error: `can't load framework: Cocoa (not found)`. Is it something I missed? This error doesn't seem to appear on the troubleshooting page. (Running on macOS 11 Big Sur using Nix)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Currently Big Sur is not supported by IHP. We are looking into it. I update you as soon as we identified all issues and updated the documentation.</strike>

There is a workaround. Using a local copy of the Framework works.
How to use a local copy: https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

IHP Issue with the same resolution: https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/issues/543#issuecomment-729824675